# Saving .txt file with write_delim and here package into subdirectory in Rmarkdown

Tags: r

The goal is to save a .txt file into a subdirectory (~/output/data/file.txt) within my project folder by using the here package in rmarkdown. It should be tab-delimited and have no col names.

This is my code that fails:

```
readr::write_delim(here::here(file, "output", "data", "file.txt", 
                delim = "\t", col_names = FALSE))
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
file <- data.frame(chromosome = c("chr1", "chr2", "chr3"),
                   start = c(10, 20, 30),
                   stop = c(100, 200, 300),
                   gene = c("geneA", "geneB", "geneC"))
```

This is the error I get:

Error in readr::write_delim(here::here(file, "output", "data", "file.txt", : is.data.frame(x) is not TRUE

I get it to work with this code, where I put in the whole path, but I want to avoid that:

```
readr::write_delim(file, "/whole/path/to/project/folder/output/data/file.txt",
                       delim = "\t", col_names = FALSE)
```

Any ideas on what is going wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like I've figured it out myself...

```
write_delim(file, here("output", "data", "file.txt"),
            col_names = FALSE, delim = "\t")
```

my order was wrong.